# libgdx button image animation strange behavior when starting new activity

Tags: android, animation, button, android-activity, libgdx

Instead of using libgdx lib for creating buttons and menu, I wrote my own code for that.

But now I am facing very strange problem in animating button.

**I have implemented very simple animaiton for button. If button was touched(i.e touchscreen was touched, but not released) I am moving button image to x = 1px right and y = 1px down. When touch screen was released, button image is reset to its original position i.e x = 1px left and  y = 1px up;**

Here is how I implemented Button:

```
public class MenuInputHandler implements InputProcessor {
....
MenuScreen menuscreen;

 public MenuInputHandler(MenuScreen menuScreen) {
    this.menuScreen = menuScreen;
}

 @Override
 public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    if(pointer==0)
        {

         this.menuScreen.setTouchStartAnimation(screenX,screenHeight-screenY);

         return true;

        }
    else        
        return true;
        // just ignoring in case of multi touch...
}

    @Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

            this.menuScreen.setTouchStopAnimation();
    return true;
}

}
```

MenuScreen class ...

```
 public class MenuScreen implements Screen{

    public enum MENU {PLAY,RATE,SOUND,NONE};    
public MENU menuTouched,menuToLoad;

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render(float arg0) {

            // other graphics code here....
            ...
            ...

            spriteBatch.draw(soundIcon,soundButtonStartX+soundAnimationOffsetX,
            soundButtonStartY-soundAnimationOffsetY,
            iconHeight,iconHeight);
            /// similarly .. for other button images .....

            // this is where I  load menu...     
    if(menuToLoad != MENU.NONE)
    {
        loadMenus();
    }

}

@Override
public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    public void setTouchStartAnimation(int x,int y)
{
    if(menuTouched!=MENU.NONE)
        return;

        // soundbound is a rectangle with coordinates for touch area...
    if((soundBound.contains(x, y)) 
        {menuTouched = MENU.SOUND;
         soundMenuAnimationOffsetX = .1f;
         soundMenuAnimationOffsetY = .1f;        
        }
    else if ...... 

            /// similarly for other...
    }


 public void setTouchStopAnimation()
 {
    // stop currently running animation


    switch(menuTouched)
    {
    case SOUND:
        soundMenuAnimationOffsetX = 0f;
        soundMenuAnimationOffsetY = 0f;
        menuToLoad = MENU.SOUND;
        break;

            /// similarly for RATE menu ... and others...

             }
}

public void loadMenus()
{
    switch(menuToLoad)
    {
    case PLAY:
                    // reseting menuToLoad
        menuToLoad = MENU.NONE;
                    // loading whatever is touched .... new Menu etc...
        onTouchPlay();
        break;

    case SOUND:
        menuToLoad = MENU.NONE;
        onTouchSound();
        break;

            case RATE:
                    menuToLoad = MENU.NONE;
                    onTouchRate();
                    break;

    }
 }

 public void onTouchRate()
 { 
     // create intent  and start new activity from MainActivity....
 }

 public void onTouchSound()
 {
   // unable disable sound .....
   // no new screen loaded...
   // just 2, 3 line of code....
  }

  public void onTouchPlay()
  {
   // load game screen.....
  }
```

}

So, In case, when I touch on sound button, play button etc.., its animation works perfectly without any issue every time. i.e when I touch screen, the image shifts with given offset, giving the feel that an event occur and when I releases touch, image shifts back to its original location as animation offset is reset to 0;

But In case, when I touched rate button which will create intent and start activity chooser or directly start new activity, following discrepancies are seen..

1. sometimes animation works perfectly as with case of sound button.
2. sometimes animation completes i.e image shift and then get back to its normal position, but then one or two more render frames are called which will show button image to shifted position( with added offset, which I already set to 0, when I released touched!!!) even when I set the offset variable to 0 in setTouchStopAnimation(). Then it will load new activity as expected and then once the activity is finished and game activity resumes, the button image is seen shifted to original position.
3. sometimes animation is not at all seen.(this may be because, things were processed too quickly as I didn't used any delay!!).. no problem as of now!... or any other reason?

**Issue is only seen with buttons whose listener starts new activity!**

I should have better used libgdx lib for menu and button to avoid such behavior.

Thanks 
vipul

Comment: Probably not the root cause, but your `touchUp` method should also ignore pointers other than 0, if `touchDown` does.  In your `render` method do you have `if` statements that might cause nothing to be drawn?  (The flickering you describe sounds like old frames showing back up.)

Comment: render method is very simple in my case. It will render images using spriteBatch and in the end just one if that will check if menuToLoad.

Answer (score 1):

**Seems like a GL thread issue**

```
 public void onTouchRate()
 { 
     // create intent  and start new activity from MainActivity....
 }
```

This code might be taking too long, and freezing the GL rendering thread (which also handles events). This might make the system to miss some events and unexpected behavior.

Event handlers are supposed to be small (computationally inexpensive) irrespective of library you use. If that code takes too long, consider shifting it to some background thread and release the Event Dispatch thread immediately.

**Note:**
There might be some things at the end of your code which require to be executed on GL thread (sometimes). In that case you may use

```
Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so I tried this .. In my onTouchRate method ..   new Thread(new Runnable(){  

   @Override
   public void run() {
    try {
     Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
   }
  }).start();   ... If I am not using delay.. then issue is still seen while If I use small delay, then also issue is seen, but with delay of 50, I guess large enough, issue is fixed. Can you explain me the reason for this.

Comment: Sending intents is a slow and heavy process which might affect performance of other things (like buttons in your case) if they are not carefully written. The threshold of 50 might be different on different devices so it's better not to rely on it. I'd suggest you to use **scene2d**. It's really easy to use and robust.